# error message automatically hide/disappear and stay on the input/form page after POST

Tags: php, html, regex, error-handling

sorry for my re-post with the same topic again. I have my form that include Phone Number and Email validation done with php, it works great, but when I click on submit button, the error message shown on the different page. I want it shows next to input field, or if it possible the error message automatically hide/disappear and stay on the input/form page! How can I do with my whole code bellow?

index.php

```
<?php
  /**
  * This function can be used to check the sanity of variables
  *
  * @access private
  *
  * @param string $type  The type of variable can be bool, float, numeric, string, array, or object
  * @param string $string The variable name you would like to check
  * @param string $length The maximum length of the variable
  *
  * return bool
  */
  function sanityCheck($string, $type, $length){
  // assign the type
  $type = 'is_'.$type;
  if(!$type($string))
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  // now we see if there is anything in the string
  elseif(empty($string))
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  // then we check how long the string is
  elseif(strlen($string) > $length)
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  else
    {
    // if all is well, we return TRUE
    return TRUE;
    }
}
/**
  * This function if the $_POST vars are set 
  *
  * @access private
  *
  * return bool
  */
  function checkSet(){
  return isset($_POST['phone'], $_POST['email']);
}
  /**
  * This function checks a number is greater than zero
  * and exactly $length digits. returns TRUE on success.
  *
  * @access private
  *
  * @param int $num The number to check
  * @param int $length The number of digits in the number
  *
  * return bool
  */

function checkNumber($phone){
   return preg_match('/^([7][7]|[7][8])([0-9]{6})$/i', $phone) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
  /**
  * This function checks if an email address in a valid format
  *
  * @access private
  *
  * @param string $email The email address to check
  *
  * return bool
  */

function checkemail($email){
  return preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $email) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

  // check all our variables are set
  if(checkSet() != FALSE)
        {
        // check the POST variable phone number is same, and is not empty
        if(empty($_POST['phone'])==FALSE && sanityCheck($_POST['phone'], 'numeric', 8) != FALSE && checkNumber($_POST['phone'], 8) == TRUE)
                {
        //If all is well we can  assign the value of POST field to a variable
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                }
        else
                {
        // if all is not well, we echo an error and exit the script
                echo 'Invalid phone number';
                // and exit the script
                exit();
                }
       // check the sanity of the useremail sent from the form
       if(sanityCheck($_POST['email'], 'string', 50) != FALSE && checkemail($_POST['email']) != FALSE)
                {
        // if the checks are ok for the email we assign the email address to a variable
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                }
        else
                {
        // if all is not well we echo an error message
                echo 'Invalid email';

        // and exit the script
                exit();
                }

    // Connect to the MySQL
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link)
            {
            die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
            }

    // select test as the current db
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('mydb', $link);
    if (!$db_selected)
            {
            die ("Database not selected : " . mysql_error());
            }

    // Build our query here and check each variable with mysql_real_escape_string()
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (phone, email)
            VALUES( '%s', '%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($phone),
            mysql_real_escape_string($email));

    // run the query
    if(!mysql_query($query))
            {
            echo 'Query failed '.mysql_error();
            exit();
            }
        else
            {
            echo '';
            }
        }

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Info</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
  <table width="320" height="350" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" background="front.jpg"><p align="center"></p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <form method="post" name="form2" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" >
          <table align="center">
            <tr valign="baseline">
              <td nowrap align="right">Phone Number:</td>
              <td><input type="numeric" name="phone" value="" size="25" maxlength="8"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="baseline">
              <td nowrap align="right">Email:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="baseline">
              <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2">
        </form>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `jquery` `validate` just to do it from client side or you can ajaxify your form post and handle the error with your own error handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your errors in an errors array.  Then, next to each input, output the error corresponding to that input.

```
if (!isset('email') errors['email'] = 'You must enter a valid email.';
// More validation

// In the form...
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php $_POST['email']; ?>" />
<?php if (isset($errors['email']) echo "<span>$errors['email']</span>"; ?>
```